# Langchain and Github - Converting Code File to Text!! I'm doing right?

Tags: python, chatgpt-api, langchain

basically what I'm trying to do is a code that allows me to take all my scripts (c#) from a repository on Github and using Langchain, enter my bot to query things from the project.

So far I was able to fetch the scripts from the repository using this loader: https://llamahub.ai/l/github_repo, and I was able to convert the code to text and generate chunks and so on. This is the text generated using Llama index and Langchain:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8D8B.png)

However when I try to run the following query:

```
with get_openai_callback() as cb:
        response = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=user_question)
        print(cb)
    
    st.write(response)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\seleg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\combine_documents\base.py", line 20, in format_document
    base_info = {"page_content": doc.page_content}
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'page_content'
```

How I can solve this if I already have the text data?!

How to use my text data into the API

Comment: you need to create Graph knowledge baseon top of yousource code first